# Automatically generate R source code to build a package

Tags: json, r, cran

I wrote bindings to an API and put everything into an R package, including tests, vignettes, etc., but the API keeps constantly changing. This brings up some issues

- updating my package is error-prone, maybe I miss a new function or forget to mark an old as deprecated
- submitting the package to CRAN is not a good idea, since it's changing frequently and packages are reviewed by hand
- I got a hard time keeping this software up2date, since the API chance irregularly and therefor I maybe miss them

I came up with the idea to generate the bindings automatically. The API itself provides everything required for that via an online JSON documentation. These docs reflect constantly the current definition of the API.

Writing some code which converts the JSON docs to R functions is not the problem. But if I do so, I still need to update the package on CRAN. The best solution would be, to create a package that (on load) looks up the API definition and creates the required functions. Ideally these functions should be unit tested.

I am thankful for any hint on that.

Best

Edit: The API is the [firebrowse API](http://firebrowse.org/api/api-docs/) with [an example](http://firebrowse.org/api/v1/Samples) of what the input would be.

Comment: It may be very hard to give an useful answer without knowing the API you are talking about.

Comment: I found some useful hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985417/dynamically-creating-a-function-within-an-r-package

Comment: I've got a crude start to a package to generate an R package from a  Swagger spec. It would not be difficult (once completed) to have be a dynamic generation. I've no cycles to devote to the pkg for a while tho.

Answer (score 0):

This is really challenging and thus there's no obvious way to do it. The whole idea behind [wsdl](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) was to be able to do this easily using a standardized XML description. That was never really implemented in R and it never really took off more broadly (because of the emergence of RESTful services and JSON).

You can definitely generate functions dynamically by creating a so-called "function factories" (Hadley discussed these a bit [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html)). In short, you write a function that takes JSON as input and returns a function that does whatever is described in the JSON. (Creating such a factory that dynamically does this whenever the package is loaded seems risky but I suppose it's possible. I'd probably just keep the factory to myself and use it to create and update the package.)

I'm not going to attempt to deal with your API specifically, but to see how this would work:

```
# create factory with arguments to control returned function
factory <- function(action, endpoint, content = TRUE, parsed = FALSE) {
    if (content) {
        if(parsed) {
            out <- function() httr::content(httr::VERB(action, endpoint))
        } else {
            out <- function() httr::content(httr::VERB(action, endpoint), "text")
        } 
    } else {
            out <- function() httr::VERB(action, endpoint)
    }
    return(out)
}

# use factory to create different functions
(a <- factory("GET", "http://example.com", content = TRUE, parsed = FALSE))
## function() httr::content(httr::VERB(action, endpoint), "text")

(b <- factory("GET", "http://example.com", content = TRUE, parsed = TRUE))
## function() httr::content(httr::VERB(action, endpoint))

(c <- factory("GET", "http://example.com", content = FALSE))
function() httr::VERB(action, endpoint)

# evaluate each function
a() # returns a character string
b() # returns parsed HTML
c() # returns an httr response object
```

Comment: Hi Thomas and thank you very much for sharing your thoughts. I did not know about the httr package before, it might come in handy. But this does not solve my problem. You really nailed it with "I'd probably just keep the factory to myself and use it to create and update the package". This is the part I want avoid. The API is changing frequently and the package should work independent from hat.

Comment: @mariodeng I'm not saying it's impossible, so you could definitely put the factory into a package, call it during `onLoad` and assign the resulting functions into the package namespace. That seems like it should be possible, but I think it will be challenging (in part because users will need internet access, it's not possible to export functions that do not yet exist, etc.).

Comment: Exactly, this is what I was thinking about too. Also I would like to use unit tests and generate a proper documentation. Hm, I think I'll stick with generating the package myself. Not perfect, but still an improvement :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

> The best solution would be, to create a package that (on load) looks up the API definition and creates the required functions. Ideally these functions should be unit tested.

This is a very well known problem. React to server changes without breaking the clients is a pain not just in your situation, but also for mobile applications (that needs to be resubmitted every time API changes).

While your approach may work (generate the client on the fly), the best result can be reached if the server may collaborate to reach the achievement.

You have to decouple the client from API implementation. How? Using REST (for real), thous introducing the concept of state and transitions.

This is not the right place to explain how it works, but a great introduction can be found in this [great presentation by Glenn Block](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vp-Na5wKlig), and then continuing to read.

This won't solve your particular problem, but it is, in my opinion, the right way to approach the problem.

You may want to have a look to [this video as well](http://mbltdev.ru/?utm_content=buffer529f4&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer), 15:24 part.